# Transferring files over TCP with CopyTo()

Tags: c#, file, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a question regarding the CopyTo() method of the Stream class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto

This approach works for small file circa 15kb as I tried it, but anything higher (I tested with 2mbs, 4 mbs and so on) and it just hangs on the CopyTo() method. Can't really figure out why.

Code sample:

---

Server's handle client :

```
public void HandleClient(object c)
{
    string path = "some path";
    using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)c)
    {
        using (NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                netStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client send :

```
public void Send()
{
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("some address"), 12345);
    string path = "some path";

    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(remoteEndPoint))
    {
        using (NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(netStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

P.s. As I research my way into Network Programming, I often find people advising other people to switch to WCF for this kind of tasks since, apparently, WCF makes everything a lot easier. What do you guys suggest and could you provide some links for a WCF noob that would be useful in modeling a LAN file sharing application since that's what my goal is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info

Comment: WCF is very powerful indeed, but unfortunately it can be hard to configure it right, there are a lot of inter-related throttling settings that may hinder you (some client side, some server side), especially when dealing with huge data transfers like the ones you want to accomplish.  The ancestor technology (.Net Remoting) was not very flexible, with many hardcoded settings.  WCF went the opposite direction and everything is uber-configurable. Even with this difficulty, it is certainly better alternative than devising your own communication protocol IMHO.

Comment: Consider using HTTP or FTP. Libraries are available. Easy to get right.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Regarding FTP, would that be a viable solution for a file sharing application? The goal is to be able to send a file to any pc in the LAN.

Comment: Instead of opening a socket, just open an HTTP endpoint. Same principle, much easier in the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the CopyTo() issue. The problem was that I was sending the file on the main thread so the whole application just chocked for larger files that took more than an instant to transfer.

Put the sending operation in a separate thread and tested sending up to 3 GB, works as it should. Now, is there any way I could track the progress of the CopyTo() operation? Seems to me that I can't and that I should do manual transfer if I want to track the progress.

Thanks to everyone involved :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can do a CopyTo with a file larger than the buffer size. Maybe, you can try to write it by splitting your file every buffer size.

Comment: CopyTo would be quite useless if the max transfer size was limited by buffer size.

Comment: @usr : Is that a statement questioning the implied statement or is it stating that Bahaika's wrong?

Comment: @D6mi I question that this answer brings the OP towards a solution. I'm justifying my downvote.

Comment: I gave a theorical solution,  I can provide a code to demonstrate what I said.

Comment: @Bahaïka If you feel like it, it can't hurt :)