# Copying a stream to a stream - Hang (TCP)

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, copy

This question's directly related to this one :

[Transfering files over TCP with CopyTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332379/transfering-files-over-tcp-with-copyto?noredirect=1#comment33946516_22332379)

I have a issue with my TCP-over-network file transfer mechanics. Basically what's happening is, the *Client* (File sender) and the *Server* (File receiver) communicate via a simple message system.

The *Client* initiates the transfer by sending a message that contains a *Send* command, followed by the length of the *Filename*, followed by the actual *Filename*. The *Server* parses the message and lets the user decide whether he/she wants to *Accept* or *Reject* the file. The appropriate message is then sent back to the *Client*. If the *Accept* command was read by the *Client*, the file transfer is initialized. This part completes successfully using either the **Stream.CopyTo()** method or via my custom solution.

This is also where the problem occurs. The *Server* doesn't move past that line of code (code shown below), the CopyTo(), just sits there indefinitely but when I close the application, the file gets transfered succesfully. Could be some threading issues or so, I'm not sure.

### Regarding threading

Both of the methods are started in their own, separate threads, as shown below.

```
Thread t = new Thread(StartListening);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_path))
{
    var t = new Thread(SendFile);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have to choose a file!", "File error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

### StartListening and SendFile

```
    private void StartListening()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(_localEndPoint);
        _listener.Start();

        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                // Buffer for reading.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;

                SetText("SERVER : Listening for connections...\r\n");
                using (TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                {
                    SetText("SERVER : A client connected!\r\n");
                    using (NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream())
                    {
                        SetText("SERVER : Waiting for the initial message...\r\n");
                        bytesRead = netStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        // Create a new Message based on the data read.
                        var message = new Message(buffer);

                        // Ask the user whether he/she wants to accept the file.
                        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to accept this file : " + message.Filename, "Accept or reject?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

                        // If the user says yes, send the accept response and start accepting the file data.
                        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            SetText("SERVER : The user accepted the file! Sending the accept response and ready for transfer...\r\n");

                            // The Message class static methods for transforming commands into byte arrays.
                            byte[] responseBytes = Message.ConvertCommandToBytes(Commands.Accept);

                            // Send the accept response.
                            netStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);

                            // Open or create the file for saving.
                            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream((@"E:\" + message.Filename), FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                SetText("Before CopyTo()\r\n");

                                // Copy the network stream to the open filestream. "DefaultBufferSize" is set to the "short.MaxValue"
                                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                                // This line never ends, it gets stuck on this line.
                                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                                netStream.CopyTo(fileStream, DefaultBufferSize);

                                SetText("After CopyTo()\r\n");

                                // Check whether the file was transfered (will add more precise checks).
                                if (File.Exists(@"E:\" + message.Filename))
                                    _fileCopied = true;
                            }
                        }
                        // If the user rejected the transfer, send the Reject response.
                        else
                        {
                            SetText("SERVER : The user rejected the file! Sending reject response...\r\n");
                            byte[] responseBytes = Message.ConvertCommandToBytes(Commands.Reject);
                            netStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // If the file was successfully transfered, send the Success message notifying the client that
                // the operation ended successfully.
                if (_fileCopied)
                {
                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to open the directory where the file was saved?",
                        "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

                    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                        Process.Start(@"E:\");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

### Send File :

```
    // Initiates the file transfer.
    private void SendFile()
    {
        // The Ip Address is user defined, read from a TextBox.
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressBox.Text);

        // Create the IpEndPoint for the Tcp Client to connect to.
        _remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, ListenPort);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        try
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
            {
                SetText("CLIENT : Connecting to the host...\r\n");

                // Attempt to connect to the Server
                client.Connect(_remoteEndPoint);

                SetText("CLIENT : Connected to the host!\r\n");

                using (NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    // The Message class has a constructor for the initial message. It just needs
                    // the Filename and it will construct the initial message that contains the
                    // [Send] command, file length and the actually filename.
                    Message message = new Message(_filename);

                    // Convert the message to a byte array.
                    byte[] messageBytes = message.ToBytes();

                    SetText("CLIENT : Sending the initial message!\r\n");

                    // Send the initial message to the server.
                    netStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                    SetText("CLIENT : Initial message sent! \r\n");
                    SetText("CLIENT : Waiting for the response...\r\n");

                    // Wait for the response for the server. [Accept] or [Reject].
                    bytesRead = netStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    SetText(String.Format("CLIENT : Received the response - {0} bytes. Analyzing...\r\n", bytesRead));

                    // Try to convert the read bytes to a command.
                    Commands command = Message.ConvertBytesToCommand(buffer);
                    SetText("CLIENT : Received this response : " + command + "\r\n");

                    // Determine the appropriate action based on the command contents.
                    if (command == Commands.Accept)
                    {
                        SetText("CLIENT : The host accepted the request. Starting file transfer...\r\n");

                        // Open the chosen file for reading. "_path" holds the user specified path.
                        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            // Initiate the file transfer.
                            fileStream.CopyTo(netStream, DefaultBufferSize);
                            SetText("CLIENT : Successfully sent the file to the host!\r\n");
                        }

                        // Wait for the [Success] or [Error] response.
                        netStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        // Convert the bytes received to a command.
                        command = Message.ConvertBytesToCommand(buffer);

                        // Act appropriately.
                        if (command == Commands.Success)
                            MessageBox.Show("The host successfully received the file!");
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show("The transfer was unsuccessful!");

                    }
                    else if(command == Commands.Reject)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The host rejected the transfer!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

### The Message class and methods

```
public enum Commands
{
    Send,
    Accept,
    Reject,
    Success,
    Error
}

class Message
{
    private Commands _command;
    private String _filename;

    public Commands Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }

    public String Filename
    {
        get { return _filename; }
    }

    public Message(string filename)
    {
        _command = Commands.Send;
        _filename = filename;
    }

    // Create a message from the passed byte array.
    public Message(byte[] bytes)
    {
        // The first four bytes is the command.
        _command = (Commands) BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

        // The seconds four bytes is the filename length.
        int nameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);

        // If there is a filename specified, "nameLength" WILL always be larger than zero.
        if (nameLength > 0)
        {
            // Get the filename from the received byte array.
            _filename = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 8, nameLength);
        }
    }

    // Convert the message to a byte array.
    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        var result = new List<byte>();

        // Add four bytes to the List.
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int) _command));

        // Get the filename length.
        int nameLength = _filename.Length;

        // Store the length into the List. If it's zero, store the zero.
        if(nameLength > 0)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(nameLength));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        // Store the filename into the List.
        result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_filename));

        // Transform the List into an array and return it.
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _command + " " + _filename;
    }

    public static byte[] ConvertCommandToBytes(Commands command)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes((int) command);
    }

    public static Commands ConvertBytesToCommand(byte[] data)
    {
        Commands command = (Commands)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        return command;
    }
}
```

### Set Text Callback

```
    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (statusBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback c = SetText;
            Invoke(c, new object[] {text});
        }
        else
        {
            statusBox.Text += text;
        }
    }

    private delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
```

In addition, since I'll have to make this fully async (I know a thread for a client connection's really bad practice), what would be the best way to accomplish this?

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in figuring out the problem, buy ya a beer! :)

Best regards,
D6mi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this one. The issue lies in the receiving side's usage of **CopyTo()** since **CopyTo()** tries to copy the entire stream and for such purposes a NetworkStream is a infinite stream so **CopyTo()** will never get to its end thus choking the whole application.

The only situation where this can work is when the client closes the connection after sending the file, then the server knows that the stream ended, but this is not applicable to my usage scenario.

I asked the same question on the MSDN forums and got this info from there, here's the link for the thread

[Solution from the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93b5757e-8b4c-46e9-895d-ff73b6192ed2/streamcopyto-network-stream-to-file-stream-hang?forum=csharpgeneral)